# How to override "set" builtin?

Tags: python, set, overriding, built-in

I want to implement the following functionality:

1. `TestClass` `values` accepts arbitrary number of `NewClass` objects
2. Only `NewClass` objects which do not have all the same attribute values get added to
   `TestClass.values`

I've come up with this:

```
class NewClass:

    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2


class TestClass:

    def __init__(self, *values):
        self.values = self._set(values)

    def _set(self, object_list):
        unique_dict = {}
        for obj in object_list:
            if list(obj.__dict__.values()) not in unique_dict.values():
                unique_dict[obj] = list(obj.__dict__.values())
        return list(unique_dict.keys())


obj1 = NewClass(1, 2)
obj2 = NewClass(1, 2)
obj3 = NewClass(5, 2)

test = TestClass(obj1, obj2, obj3)
```

Only `obj1` and `obj3` are in the `test.values`

I am wondering how to do it in "protocol" way, such as `len` or `add`, etc.

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.values)
```

And does the second approach have meaningful benefits compared to the first one?

Comment: By "set builtin", do you mean the data type `set`? Otherwise, there exists `__setattr__` and `__setitem__`, but I don't know of anything that's just `set`.

Comment: Yes, I should have put the link in the question to avoid ambiguity.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set

Comment: ...anyhow, I suppose the "protocol way" to implement this is to override the hash mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so `_set` method is fine?

Comment: I'll add an answer.

Comment: `_set` is a really strange name for that method, btw

Comment: BTW, when your NewClass is really this simple, think about using `collections.namedtuple`, which will give you this property "for free".

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I will look into that but I have more complicated problem and this is mere simplification of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `value1` and `value2` are immutable (integers, strings and tuples are fine; lists and dicts are not), you can hash them -- implementing both `__hash__` and `__eq__` will allow the built-in set type to identify duplicates.

```
class NewClass:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.value1, self.value2))
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value1 == other.value1 and self.value2 == other.value2
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'NewClass(%r, %r)' % (self.value1, self.value2)

print(set([NewClass(1,2), NewClass(1,2), NewClass(3,4)]))
```

...properly returns:

```
{NewClass(1, 2), NewClass(3, 4)}
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for, also great point on mutability of `value1` and `value2`

Comment: I think it would be worth mentioning dataclasses here. Like `@dataclass(frozen=True)` which would handle this boilerplate for you.

Comment: Made an answer myself to highlight that.

Comment: @flakes, thank you for that -- Python hasn't been my primary language for several years now; back when I was writing it full-time, the closest thing was `collections.namedtuple`, so there's a lot of benefit to having a complete answer from someone more familiar with the modern library.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy definitely worth taking a look into dataclasses and type hint annotations then. They make it feel like an entirely different language these days. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to both of these answers... Using a frozen dataclass can avoid a lot of the boilerplate. Not only does it generate `__hash__`, `__eq__`, and `__repr__` for you, but it also enforces immutability for the lifetime of the object.

Writing `__hash__` and `__eq__` are not conceptually hard to do, but it is notoriously easy to get them wrong. Updates to class definitions such as adding or removing attributes, changing attribute data-types, etc, can leave room for differences between the class attributes and the hashing methods.

This issue to me is the biggest motivation for using dataclasses. You create concise, simple immutable types which you can hash on easily. You leave the tedious work of listing or comparing attributes to the dataclass wrapper and only have to work with the more human readable format of the class.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class NewClass:
    value1: int
    value2: int

obj1 = NewClass(1, 2)
obj2 = NewClass(1, 2)
obj3 = NewClass(5, 2)

test = {obj1, obj2, obj3}
print(test)
```

```
{NewClass(value1=1, value2=2), NewClass(value1=5, value2=2)}
```

Comment: Definitely a needed addition covering possible pitfalls, and a great explanation as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you define `__hash__` and `__eq__` on `NewClass`, you can pass instances to `set()` and it will use this functions to determine if the objects are equal in terms of the set. You need to be careful for mutable instances, since the properties can change after the fact.

Here's a simple example:

```
class NewClass:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
    def __hash__(self):
        # take the hash of the tuple
        return hash((self.value1, self.value2))
    def __eq__(self,other):
        # are the tuples equal?
        return (self.value1, self.value2) == (other.value1, other.value2)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'NewClass({self.value1}, {self.value2})'

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, *values):
        self.values = list(set(values))


obj1 = NewClass(1, 2)
obj2 = NewClass(1, 2)
obj3 = NewClass(5, 2)

test = TestClass(obj1, obj2, obj3)

test.values
# Only the different instances:
# [NewClass(1, 2), NewClass(5, 2)]
```

Comment: Very helpful warning on mutability.